# How to insert a new object into an entity and create a relationship to an existing object in another entity in Core data Relationships

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, core-data

I am wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help me with a core data related problem. I am building a iPhone app and now need to create a relationship from one entity to another.

I am new to core data, objective c and quite frankly the whole app development process so if you do have an answer please bare in mind I may find it hard to understand :-( I have spent a very long time scanning the web and reading Apple's documentation and just can't get my head around this problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think your question, as it's currently drafted, is too broad for Stack Overflow.  It would help greatly if you could edit your post to provide more detail: what are the entities?  How (in layman's terms) are they related?  Do you conceptually understand, but need help with implementing?  Or are there particular concepts you do not understand?  Have you tried setting the relationship (if so, what went wrong?).

Answer (score 0):

maintaining a relation is confusing in core data.I would like to refer magical records library for the core data relations it will work on the base of key value coding pair need not to maintain relations if we want to fetch the data from the another table we can fetch using common attribute from that table .please refer this link to understand about one to one and one to many relations https://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates .Hope this will help you